# Using pandas to drop all observations in a group after a condition has been met

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that is basically an unbalanced panel. All I want to do is, for each group, drop all observations after a condition has been met. So given this dataset:

```
person    period    hasTattoo
  A         1          N
  A         2          Y
  A         3          Y
  A         4          Y
  B         1          N
  B         2          N
  C         1          Y
  C         2          Y
```

I want to get this:

```
person    period    hasTattoo
  A         1          N
  A         2          Y
  B         1          N
  B         2          N
  C         1          Y
```

I only include periods where the condition is not met, and the period when it is met, nothing after. In R I can just use data.table.

```
dat[, subCount := 1:.N, by = c("person", "hasTattoo")]
dat <- dat[!(hasTattoo=="Y" & subCount > 1),]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For pandas 0.12

```
def f(df):
    mask = np.cumsum((df.hasTattoo == "Y").values) <= 1
    return df[mask]

df.groupby("person").apply(f)
```

for pandas 0.13

```
def f(df):
    mask = (df.hasTattoo == "Y").cumsum() <= 1
    return df[mask]

df.groupby("person").apply(f)
```

Comment: Huzzah! Thank you, thank you. Sorry for the stupid question, but what is the .values method for?

Comment: `.values` get the raw ndarray values, I use this because there are some bugs in my pandas version (0.12) that can't cumsum bool Series. This is fixed in 0.13, so you can use `.cumsum()` method of Series object.

Comment: No cumulative or in pandas?